# Fill array with coordinates within geographical bounds in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, coordinates, loop, array

I want to create an array and fill it with geographical coordinates I get from a bounds variable. Basically, a for-loop shall create coordinate pairs within the specified bounds with a fixed distance between each coordinate pair. See example code:

```
var arr = [],
    bounds = [[ 59.37519, 18.04616],[ 59.3606, 18.08169]],

for (var latitude = bounds[0][0], longitude = bounds[0][1]; latitude > bounds[1][0] && longitude < bounds[1][1]; latitude=latitude-0.003, longitude=longitude+0.003 ){
                    var lat = latitude,
                    lon = longitude;
              arr.push(lat,lon);

                    console.log(lat);
                 }
```

The current result looks like this: 
[image]

Q1: I would like to fill each row entirely until i reach the lower right corner.

Q2: It would be nice to fill the array in the format of the bounds variable as coordinate pairs. At the moment it looks like: [ 59.37519, 18.04616, 59.37489, 18.04646, 59.37459,...]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use two nested loops:

```
for (var i = minLat; i <= maxLat; i+=0.03) {
    for (var j = minLng; j <= maxLng; j+=0.03) {
        arr.push([i,j]);
    }
}
```

Also,

> with a fixed distance between each coordinate pair.

keep in mind that the earth is not a flat surface, so a difference of 0.03 degrees of longitude is not the same over different latitudes.

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks. Do you have an efficient idea for the fixed distance, too? Recalculate to meters? Other projection? Just in case, because I think that the area is sufficiently small to neglect this issue.

Comment: Overlaying a square grid on the surface of a geoid is, unfortunately, a **very** difficult problem in geodesy. As long as you are aware there is an error, and the error is small enough for your application, you should be fine.

Comment: Found [this formula](https://knowledge.safe.com/articles/725/calculating-accurate-length-in-meters-for-lat-long.html) with global precision of +-1m and it seems to do it pretty well.

Comment: do you also know a way to connect the coordinate pairs by a polyline throughout the whole raster? The polyline should be like in agriculture, where tractor drivers harvest parallel lines.